# sympy: Using Wild symbols as input for function

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Consider the following expression in python/sympy:

```
from sympy.abc import x, y
expression = 3*x**2*y**1 + x**2*y**3
```

Now I want to replace `x**n*y**m` by `max(n,m)` by using pattern matching:

```
from sympy import Wild
n = Wild('n')
m = Wild('m')
expression = expression.replace(x**n*y**m,max(n,m))
```

However, I get a `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "wild.py", line 15, in <module>
     expression = expression.replace(x**n*y**m,max(n,m))
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sympy/core/relational.py", line 103, in __nonzero__
     raise TypeError("cannot determine truth value of\n%s" % self)
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of
    m_ > n_
```

The Problem apparently is that upon matching the expression sympy does not convert the value of the Wild symbol to the matched value before forwarding it to the `max`-function. Is there any way to make this work?

Please note that this a simple example of a more general problem I have, so a workaround that does not generalize well is not very helpful. I especially hope that there is a solution using expression matching.

**Update**: Following sandwich's suggestion and replacing `max(n,m)` by `(m+n+abs(m-n))/2` works, however, the function I am using in my real program is much more complicated.
Concerning the problem mentioned by sandwich that `replace` performs substitutions starting at the bottom of the expression tree: if I use `exact=True` and define `f = sympy.Function('f')` then the following works (except that I will have to deal with some cases separately):

```
expression = expression.replace(x**n*y**m,f(n,m),exact=True)
```

It still, however, does not work for `max(n,m)`.

Comment: Replacing `max(m,n)` with mathematically equivalent `(m+n+abs(m-n))/2` helps with the error you ran into. But there is a bigger problem, in that `replace` performs substitutions  starting at the bottom of the expression tree. So, `x**2*y**3` will be replaced by 1, because it is `x*x*y*y*y`, where each of five terms is replaced by 1.

Comment: @soup `x**2*y**3` is represented as `Mul(Pow(x, 2), Pow(y, 3))`, not `Mul(x, x, y, y, y)`. In fact the only way to represent the latter is to explicitly create it with `evaluate=False`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>`max` is the built in Python function, which tries to evaluate immediately, hence the error (it can't determine which of `n` and `m` are larger when they are symbolic). You probably want the SymPy `Max` function, which works symbolically. The `my_func` you defined in your answer is effectively a basic implementation of `Max`.</strike>

```
In [14]: expression = expression.replace(x**n*y**m, Max(n,m))

In [15]: expression
Out[15]: 4
```

It seems this doesn't work (the answer 4 is wrong). The problem is that it's matching `x**2` as `x**2*y**0`. Since the mathematical value of the replacement function depends on the form of the expression, this is problematic, since SymPy is trying to be smart. You can actually make `n` and `m` not match 0 with `Wild('n', exclude=[x, 0])`, but then there is an issue that it doesn't match `x**2*y` as `x**2*y**1`.

So I recommend converting your expression to a polynomial and doing the replacement exactly. Hopefully this generalizes well to what you are actually doing

```
In [18]: Poly(expression, x, y)
Out[18]: Poly(x**2*y**3 + 3*x**2*y, x, y, domain='ZZ')

In [19]: Poly(expression, x, y).terms()
Out[19]: [((2, 3), 1), ((2, 1), 3)]

In [20]: sum(max(pows)*coeff for pows, coeff in Poly(expression, x, y).terms())
Out[20]: 9
```

Comment: Thanks, however this answer is problematic on several levels: first of all it gives the wrong answer: as can easily checked by manual calculation the result should not be 4 but instead it should be 9. This error comes from the fact that the expression is replaced by `3*Max(1,0)^2*Max(0,1)^2 + Max(1,0)^2*Max(0,2)^3` as can be easily seen by using a dummy function. Using the flag `exact=True` is a bit better, however, in this case the `3*x**2*y**1` part of the expression is not caught. Lastly as I have stated before I want to be able to use more complicated functions than `max`...

Comment: ...(cont.) resolving all these issues leads to my answer. I might know how to improve my answer to improve the execution time, if I will find time I will investigate that.

Comment: @kalix I see. The real problem is that `x**n*y**m -> Max(n, m)` isn't well-defined in the mathematical sense. I updated the answer with a more direct solution using `Poly`.

Comment: Yes this works great and is much faster than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found a solution, it is note very pretty though which might have to do with the fact that I know little about writing functions that interact nicely with sympy.

At first I import everything relevant:

```
import sympy
from sympy.abc import x, y, a, b,z
from sympy import Wild
from sympy import Function
```

Then I define my own function which will return the maximum, here returning max(x,y) could be replaced by a more complicated function:

```
class my_func(Function):
  @classmethod
  def eval(cls, x, y):
    if x.is_Number and y.is_Number:
      return max(x,y)
```

The expression I want to modify is:

```
3*x**2*y**1 + x**2*y**3
```

The I define the necessary wild symbols and a sympy function which is used temporarily to make replacements without evaluation:

```
n = Wild('n')
m = Wild('m')
k = Wild('k')
f = Function('f')
expression = expression.replace(x,f(1,0),exact=True)
expression = expression.replace(y,f(0,1),exact=True)
expression = expression.replace(f(1,0)**n,f(n,0),exact=True)
expression = expression.replace(f(0,1)**n,f(0,n),exact=True)
expression = expression.replace(k*f(0,m)*f(n,0),k*f(n,m),exact=True)
```

These replacements catch all the cases which come up in my problem. In the last step I replace `f` by `my_func` which does the evaluation.

```
expression = expression.replace(f(n,m),my_func(n,m))
```

Maybe somebody will find a nicer solution....